# Issue with POST JSON to a Jersey REST service

Tags: java, ajax, json, rest, jersey

I have a problem with posting JSON to a Jersey REST service - GET is working perfectly but POST seems tricky. I've been working on this problem for awhile now, with no solution so far. Any help is much appreciated!

It seems it cant find the U RL to send the json?Here is what FireBug console shows:

```
    POST http://localhost:9998/data 400 Bad Request
    Post source: name=Tony
    **Response Headers**
    Connection  close
    Content-Length  0
    Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    Date    Fri, 20 Apr 2012 10:13:24 GMT
    **Request Headers**
    Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language sv-se,sv;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
    Connection  keep-alive
    Content-Length  9
    Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Host    localhost:9998
    Referer http://localhost:9998/static/page.html
    User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
    X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

I'm doing the POST as follows:

```
<button id='btn' value="knapp" name="knapp" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/data',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {name:"Tony"},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    })
</script>
```

Javabean class with @XmlRootElement:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class StatusBean {
    private String name;

    public StatusBean() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Resource method:

```
@Path("/data")
public class PostData {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public StatusBean post(StatusBean sb) {
        System.out.println(sb);
        return sb;
    }
}
```

The server, set up with Grizzly:

```
public class Main {
    public static final URI BASE_URI = getBaseURI();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer httpServer = startServer();

        Map<String,String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "server");
        SelectorThread selector = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create("http://localhost:9998/", initParams );

        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nTry out %shelloworld\nHit enter to stop it...",
                BASE_URI, BASE_URI));

        System.in.read();
        httpServer.stop();
    }

    protected static HttpServer startServer() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Starting grizzly...");

        ClassNamesResourceConfig rc = new ClassNamesResourceConfig(PostData.class);

//        rc.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);

        HttpServer server = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);

        server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler(new File(".").getAbsolutePath()), "/static");

        return server;
    }

    private static int getPort(int defaultPort) {
        String port = System.getProperty("jersey.test.port");
        if (null != port) {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(port);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        }
        return defaultPort;
    }

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(getPort(9998)).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: check the server log, is there anything there - look for an exception and paste stack trace.

Comment: Nothing in the server log, thats the problem

Comment: Can you post your web.xml, so we can see JAX-RS config?

Comment: There isnt a web.xml file, i set up the server with Grizzly, so there's no deploy or such things needed, adding the server code now.

Comment: I guess you need to pass REST config information to Grizzly, see my answer below

Comment: How are you running the server? From the command line? If so, you should see exception stack traces in the console. If you are running it from an IDE, it should be able to show the standard output of the program - check that - there should be log messages and exceptions.

Comment: @nihulus Did u get solution i am also facing similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094620/unable-to-make-cors-post-request-in-javascript-to-java-web-servicejersey

Answer (score 2):

1. Try making your bean serializable.

   ```
   @XmlRootElement

   public class StatusBean implements Serializable {
   ....
   }
   ```
2. Check your POST url. It should be `

   http://localhost:9998/{projectname}/{restservletmapping}/data

   For example, if my web.xml looks like this and my project name is SampleProject

   ```
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

   URL would be : http://localhost:9998/SampleProject/rest/data

   You can use tools for testing REST services like [SOAP UI](http://www.eviware.com/%22SOAP%20UI%22) or browser addons like POSTMAN, REST CONSOLE, etc.
3. If above things are fine and REST service is giving response with testing tools.
   Then it could be problem of Cross Origin Policy in ajax.

Comment: My object is serialized dynamically and doesn't need the interface, but it lacked setter and this reminded me of that fact.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The issue is that your data is not converted to JSON string automatically.
So you just need to call JSON.stringify(...) on your data before posting it:

```
<button id='btn' value="knapp" name="knapp" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/data',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({name:"Tony"}),
        dataType: 'json'
    });
})
</script>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

From your server config I see that you haven't configured JAX-RS with Grizzly. On the base of that [example](http://viewfromthefringe.blogspot.com/2009/06/jax-rs-hello-world.html) you should somehow pass such property

```
Map<String,String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
initParams.put( "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "package.with.your.StatusBean.class" );
```

Another configuration option is to use

```
ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("your.package.with.resources");
```

and start grizzly server:

```
GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
```

See details: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html (Chapter "Deploying the root resource"). Try to run first example they have.

Comment: Ok, i checked the example and added these:       

  Map<String,String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "server");
        SelectorThread selector = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create( "http://localhost:9998/", initParams );

But still getting 400 bad request...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the path you're posting to is complete? You should define another `Path` annotation on the `post` method and use that in the URL you're posting to:

```
@Path("/data")
public class PostData {
    @Path("/postStatus")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public StatusBean post(StatusBean sb) {
        System.out.println(sb);
        return sb;
    }
}
```

Then use the `/data/postStatus` path to post your request to:

```
<button id='btn' value="knapp" name="knapp" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/data/postStatus',

            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {name:"Tony"},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: He's getting 400 Bad request, not 404 Not found, so it seems the path is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgotten to register the JSON mapper, i.e. Jackson (or whatever mapper you use). The feature is not enabled automatically, you have to load the class in your ResourceConfig:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature.class
```

[sample](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.26-b08/examples/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/jackson/MyApplication.java)

[also, see JSON howto](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json)