# Unable to make CORS POST request in javascript to java web service(jersey)?

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, jersey, cors

I am implementing Cross Resource Origin Sharing in Java Web services using Jersey.I created resource as followes:

```
@POST
    @Path("/getSubjects")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getSubjects(TokenCheck tc) throws IOException, ServletException{ 
        String token = tc.getToken();
        String result = "";
        if(!token.equals("") && !token.equals(null)){
            context.getRequestDispatcher("/GetSubjectsWs?token="+token).include(request, response);
            String subs = request.getAttribute("subjects").toString();
            result = "{\"subjects\":\""+subs+"\"}";
        }else {
            result = "{\"subjects\":\"['Invalid Token login again']\"}";
        }
        JSONObject j = null;
        try {
            j = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity(j).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS").header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type:application/json").build(); 
    }
```

and making post request using javascript as :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JavaScript Client</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function restReq() {
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/WebservicesServer/restful/getserver/getSubjects";
    var json = {
            "token":"8495C211F11C9B18E6651E03EB2995BC"
    };
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open("POST", url, true);
    client.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Request-Methods", "POST");
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    client.send(json);
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (client.readyState == 4) {
           if ( client.status == 200) 
               console.log("success: " + client.responseText);
          else
              console.log("error: " +client.status+" "+ client.responseText);
       }
 };
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="getSubjects" onclick="restReq();">
</body>
</html>
```

When i clicked getSubjects Button in chrome I am getting **error as : XMLHttpRequest cannot load ..localhost:8888/WebservicesServer/restful/getserver/getSubjects. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin**. **But i am able to get response with GET request**,problem is with POST request
my browser url file:///E:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Srinivas/Desktop/wars/JSClient2.html
(File system)  I tried in many ways like by setting origin etc, still unable to get json response (Server is Tomcat 7) please help to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using CORS then you should implement it as a filter rather than attempt to embed it in every method of every resource.  Here's a simple example (you might want to tweak the settings to restrict it if that's of concern to you):

```
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

/**
 * Filter to handle cross-origin resource sharing.
 */
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter
{
  private static final String ORIGINHEADER = "Origin";
  private static final String ACAOHEADER = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
  private static final String ACRHHEADER = "Access-Control-Request-Headers";
  private static final String ACAHHEADER = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";

  public CORSFilter()
  {
  }

  @Override
  public ContainerResponse filter(final ContainerRequest request, final ContainerResponse response)
  {
    final String requestOrigin = request.getHeaderValue(ORIGINHEADER);
    response.getHttpHeaders().add(ACAOHEADER, requestOrigin);

    final String requestHeaders = request.getHeaderValue(ACRHHEADER);
    response.getHttpHeaders().add(ACAHHEADER, requestHeaders);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply . so i have register this filter in web.xml and request to resource as before and this will add header to the response?

Comment: Yep this will be added to all responses.